# Snoopy can balance on an edge atop his doghouse. Is any reason given for this?

Tags: comics, peanuts, charles-m-schulz

In Peanuts, Snoopy sleeps and does other activities on top of his doghouse. Since the doghouse has a pointy roof, shouldn't he fall down? Why doesn't the below happen every time?

[image: Snoopy rolling off dog-house]

Is there a reason provided, in the comic or any extratextual material, as to why he is able to do this?

Comment: When I was growing up, I had the coin bank pictured below showing the doghouse with a flat roof. No idea if this conflicts with canon, though. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Shky7.jpg

Comment: Keep in mind, the kind of answer SFF gives to this question (canonical reasons provided by exogenous texts) is different than the kind of answer Lit usually gives (any other analytic reasons why, i.e. "doing it this way served an aesthetic purpose"). We don't usually take the word of the author as law, here, which makes the voting and answers here... odd.

Comment: how is this better for lit than SciFi?

Comment: @user17915 - By simple virtue of being on-topic here, and off-topic there. There was a long and heated discussion, which ultimately solidly fell in favor of declaring *Peanuts* "not speculative fiction." By contrast, while asking for a specific textual justification might be a more...unusual school of interpretation here, [tag:comics] of all sorts seem solidly on-topic.

Answer (score 156):

### His brain sends a message to his ears, which lock him to the top of the doghouse.

Charles Schulz seems to have addressed this question only once, in the 25th anniversary book "The Peanuts Jubilee". I haven't found this anywhere online (including the Peanuts Wikia) so I thought I'd upload it and share it here.

> The more Snoopy moved into his life of fantasy, the more important it became for his doghouse to remain in side view. You simply cannot have a dog doing and thinking the things that Snoopy does on a realistic doghouse. The image is much more acceptable when the doghouse is drawn only from the side. When necessary, it almost loses its identity completely. Snoopy's typewriter could never balance on the peak the way it does and, of course, Snoopy himself is somewhat of a mystery when one examines his sleeping pose closely. I once inquired of a veterinarian how birds stay on tree limbs when they fall asleep. He told me that their claws receive a message from their brain after they have fallen asleep, which tightens a certain muscle, keeping them from tumbling off the branch. He said a similar thing occurs to horses, allowing them to sleep while standing. Humans do not have this ability. When I am asked how Snoopy remains on top of his doghouse after falling asleep, I am now able to say that his brain sends a message to his ears, which lock him to the top of his doghouse.
>    <sub>Sources [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzTg7.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezatL.jpg)</sub>

### Update:

[A commenter on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/peanuts/comments/8virs7/theres_a_canon_reason_how_snoopy_stays_balanced/e1oy1jv/) pointed out that Charles Schulz references this in the [April 29, 1963 strip](https://www.gocomics.com/peanuts/1963/04/29):

[image]